# PowerShell Script To Find Where SharePoint 2010 Features Are Activated

Tags: powershell, feature, feature-activation

I want a PowerShell script to find where Features are activated in a site collection and its sites/subsites

Like for example  feature "Enterprise feature"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might also help someone:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All| Where-Object {(Get-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Site $_.Url) -ne $null } | Select Url
```

Taken from [this blog post](http://paddyt.blogspot.ca/2012/04/powershell-to-find-site-collections.html). 
See full reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607945.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through all sites/webs for specific web application and call this snippet:

```
$o.Features | ? { $_.DefinitionId -eq 'featureId' } | % { $_.Parent }
```

Where $o can be SPWebApplication, SPSite or SPWeb object

EDIT: fullscript

```
$url = "http://localhost"
$featureId = "00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107"

$s = Get-SPSite $url

Function FindFeature($obj, $fId) 
{
  $obj.Features | ? { $_.DefinitionId -eq $fId } | % { $_.Parent.Url }

  $obj.AllWebs | % {

    $_.Features | ? { $_.DefinitionId -eq $featureId } | % { $_.Parent.Url }    
    if ($_.AllWebs.Count -gt 0) {
      FindFeature($_, $fId);
    }
  }
}

FindFeature $s $featureId
```